# Pasar una respuesta json a listview android

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente codigo y quiero pasar la respuesta del jsonarray en un listview pero fuera del metodo donde se obtiene el response no me deja utilizar los datos. Yo lleno el arraylist pero cuando intento utilizarlo en el oncreate me dice que esta vacio!!!

```
RequestQueue queue;


TextView text1;

ListView lista;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public static ArrayList<String> lis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    lis=new ArrayList<String>();

    Makerequest();

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,lis);

    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private  void Makerequest(){
    try {



        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String url ="https://androidfe.herokuapp.com/items";

        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try{

                            for (int g=0;g<response.length();g++){

                             lis.add(response.getJSONObject(g).getString("Descripcion"));


                            }



                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            text1.setText(e.toString());
                        }

                    }



                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        text1.setText(error.toString());

                    }
                });



        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lis.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    catch (Exception java){

       text1.setText(java.toString());
    }
}
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo y quiero pasar la respuesta del jsonarray en un listview pero fuera del metodo donde se obtiene el response no me deja utilizar los datos. Yo lleno el arraylist pero cuando intento utilizarlo en el oncreate me dice que esta vacio!!!

Answer (score 0):

pues quizás tengas conflictos ya que estas usando como base java, podrías probar pasando jsonarray a objetos te recomiendo utilizar gson

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Con este ejemplo espero ayudarte

```
 String json = CADENA_JSON;    
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 List<Tu_objeto> frutas = gson.fromJson(CADENA_JSON, Tu_objeto.class);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(org.json.JSONObject, java.lang.Class<com.example.itco.rest.Respuesta>)'

Comment: gson.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(t), Respuesta.class);No funciono

Comment: Puedes imprimir lo que tienes en el json, y tu objeto. Porque puede dar problemas de compatibilidad

Comment: No no es eso. La peticion esta bien y los datos estan llegando bien, lo que pasa esque solo los puedo utilizar dentro del metodo onResponse el cual no me permite agregar los datos a un listview . Solo he podido sacarlos en un Textview pero quiero que sea un listview. Es como si no se grabara la informacion en el arraylist o lo que sea. Y fuera de ese metodo no puedo utilizar esos datos que recibo en la respuesta. Creo que voy a tener que guardar esos datos en una base de datos sqlite pero perderia la gracia porque para que entonces usar el servicio rest?

Comment: Como haria yo una peticion rest , guardar los datos recibidos en un arraylist y luego fuera o en cualquier parte llenar el listview con el arraylist ??